# How to solve the dimension error and effectively use Conv2dTranspose?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

i have created a discriminator and generator file to implement GAN, however, i am facing this error.

The initial error i was facing was in the main.py file where i am calling the criterion library and passing the output and label. I solved that error using squeeze function, so that the issue of shape was resolved.

Before using squeeze , an error showed that the shapes of output and labels were not matching  ( the shapes were (7,1,1,1) and (7) for the output and the label respectively.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
class generatorG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(generatorG, self).__init__()

        self.t1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 64, kernel_size= (4,4), stride = 2,padding = 1),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace = True)
        )

        self.t2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels= 64, out_channels = 64, kernel_size = (4,4), stride = 2,padding = 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace = True)
        )

        self.t3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 64, out_channels = 128, kernel_size = 4, stride = 2, padding =1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace = True)
        )
        self.t4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride = 2,padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        )

        self.t5 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        )
        self.t6 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=4000, kernel_size=(4, 4)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(4000),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

        self.t7 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 512, out_channels = 256, kernel_size =4, stride = 2, padding = 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

        self.t8 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

        self.t9 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

        self.t10 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=3, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.t1(x)
        x = self.t2(x)
        x = self.t3(x)
        x = self.t4(x)
        x = self.t5(x)
        x = self.t6(x)
        x = self.t7(x)
        x = self.t8(x)
        x = self.t9(x)
        x = self.t10(x)

        return x


model = generatorG()
print(model(torch.randn()).shape)
```

Discriminator File

```
import torch
from torch import nn

class DiscriminatorD(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DiscriminatorD, self).__init__()

        self.t1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 64, kernel_size =4, stride = 2, padding = 1),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace = True)
        )

        self.t2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 64, out_channels = 128, kernel_size = 4, stride = 2, padding = 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace = True)
        )

        self.t3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        )

        self.t4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        )

        self.t5 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=1, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.t1(x)
        x = self.t2(x)
        x = self.t3(x)
        x = self.t4(x)
        x = self.t5(x)

        return x
```

main.py file

```
from generator import *
from discriminator import *
import argparse
import os
import random
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.parallel
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data
import torchvision.datasets as dset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.utils as vutils
from torch.autograd import Variable

import utils

epochs = 100
Batch_Size = 64
lr = 0.0002
beta1 = 0.5
over = 4
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--dataroot', default = 'dataset/train', help = 'path to dataset')
opt = parser.parse_args()

try:
    os.makedirs('result/train/cropped')
    os.makedirs('result/train/real')
    os.makedirs('result/train/recon')
    os.makedirs('model/')

except:
    pass

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Scale(128),
                                transforms.CenterCrop(128),
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5,0.5,0.5), (0.5,0.5,0.5))])
dataset = dset.ImageFolder(root=opt.dataroot, transform= transform)
assert dataset

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=Batch_Size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
wtl2 = 0.999

def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv')!=-1:
        m.weight.data.normal_(0.0,0.2)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm')!=-1:
        m.weight.data.normal_(1.0, 0.02)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0)

resume_epoch = 0
netG = generatorG()
netG.apply(weights_init)

netD = DiscriminatorD()
netD.apply(weights_init)

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
criterionMSE = nn.MSELoss()

input_real = torch.FloatTensor(Batch_Size, 3, 128, 128)
input_cropped = torch.FloatTensor(Batch_Size, 3, 128, 128)
label = torch.FloatTensor(Batch_Size)
real_label = 1
fake_label = 0

real_center = torch.FloatTensor(Batch_Size, 3, 64, 64)

input_real = Variable(input_real)
input_cropped = Variable(input_cropped)
label = Variable(label)

real_center = Variable(real_center)

optimizerD = optim.Adam(netD.parameters(), lr = lr, betas=(beta1, 0.999))
optimizerG = optim.Adam(netG.parameters(), lr = lr, betas = (beta1, 0.999))
over = 4
for epoch in range(resume_epoch, epochs):
    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
        real_cpu, _ = data
        real_center_cpu = real_cpu[:,:,int(128/4):int(128/4)+int(128/2),int(128/4):int(128/4)+int(128/2)]
        batch_size = real_cpu.size(0)

        with torch.no_grad():
            input_real.resize_(real_cpu.size()).copy_(real_cpu)
            input_cropped.resize_(real_cpu.size()).copy_(real_cpu)
            real_center.resize_(real_center_cpu.size()).copy_(real_center_cpu)
            input_cropped[:, 0, int(128 / 4 + over):int(128 / 4 + 128 / 2 - over),int(128 / 4 + over):int(128 / 4 + 128 / 2 - over)] = 2 * 117.0 / 255.0 - 1.0
            input_cropped[:, 1, int(128 / 4 + over):int(128 / 4 + 128 / 2 - over),int(128 / 4 + over):int(128 / 4 + 128 / 2 - over)] = 2 * 104.0 / 255.0 - 1.0
            input_cropped[:, 2, int(128 / 4 + over):int(128 / 4 + 128 / 2 - over),int(128 / 4 + over):int(128 / 4 + 128 / 2 - over)] = 2 * 123.0 / 255.0 - 1.0

        netD.zero_grad()
        with torch.no_grad():
            label.resize_(batch_size).fill_(real_label)

        output = netD(real_center)
        # output = torch.unsqueeze(output[0, 1)
        output = torch.squeeze(output, 1)
        output = torch.squeeze(output, 1)
        output = torch.squeeze(output, 1)
        print(output.shape)
        # label = label.unsqueeze(1)
        # label = label.unsqueeze(1)
        # label = label.unsqueeze(1)

        print(label.shape)
        errD_real = criterion(output, label)
        errD_real.backward()
        D_x = output.data.mean()
        print(input_cropped.shape)
        fake = netG(input_cropped)
        label.data.fill_(fake_label)
        output = netD(fake.detach())
        errD_fake = criterion(output, label)
        errD_fake.backward()
        D_G_z1 = output.data.mean()
        errD = errD_real + errD_fake
        optimizerD.step()

        netG.zero_grad()
        label.data.fill_(real_label)  # fake labels are real for generator cost
        output = netD(fake)
        errG_D = criterion(output, label)

        wtl2Matrix = real_center.clone()
        wtl2Matrix.data.fill_(wtl2 * 10)
        wtl2Matrix.data[:, :, int(over):int(128 / 2 - over), int(over):int(128 / 2 - over)] = wtl2

        errG_l2 = (fake - real_center).pow(2)
        errG_l2 = errG_l2 * wtl2Matrix
        errG_l2 = errG_l2.mean()

        errG = (1 - wtl2) * errG_D + wtl2 * errG_l2

        errG.backward()
        D_G_z2 = output.data.mean()
        optimizerG.step()

        print('[%d / %d][%d / %d] Loss_D: %.4f Loss_G: %.4f / %.4f l_D(x): %.4f l_D(G(z)): %.4f'
              % (epoch, epochs, i, len(dataloader),
                 errD.data, errG_D.data, errG_l2.data, D_x, D_G_z1,))

        if i % 100 == 0:
            vutils.save_image(real_cpu,
                              'result/train/real/real_samples_epoch_%03d.png' % (epoch))
            vutils.save_image(input_cropped.data,
                              'result/train/cropped/cropped_samples_epoch_%03d.png' % (epoch))
            recon_image = input_cropped.clone()
            recon_image.data[:, :, int(128 / 4):int(128 / 4 + 128 / 2), int(128 / 4):int(128 / 4 + 128 / 2)] = fake.data
            vutils.save_image(recon_image.data,
                              'result/train/recon/recon_center_samples_epoch_%03d.png' % (epoch))
```

utils file

```
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torch.autograd import Variable

def load_image(filename, size = None, scale = None):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    if size is not None:
        img = img.resize((size, size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    elif scale is not None:
        img = img.resize((int(img.size[0]/scale), int(img.size[1]/scale)), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    return img

def save_image(filename, data):
    img = data.clone().add(1).div(2).mul(255).clamp(0,255).numpy()
    img = img.transpose(1,2,0).astype('uint8')
    img = Image.fromarray(img)
    img.save(filename)

def gram_matrix(y):
    (b, ch, h, w) = y.size()
    features = y.view(b, ch, w*h)
    features_t = features.transpose(1,2)
    gram = features.bmm(features_t)/(ch*h*w)
    return gram

def normalize_batch(batch):
    mean = batch.data.new(batch.data.size())
    std = batch.data.new(batch.data.size())
    mean[:, 0, :, :] = 0.485
    mean[:, 1, :, :] = 0.456
    mean[:, 2, :, :] = 0.406
    std[:, 0, :, :] = 0.229
    std[:, 1, :, :] = 0.224
    std[:, 2, :, :] = 0.225
    batch = torch.div(batch, 255.0)
    batch -= Variable(mean)
    # batch /= Variable(std)
    batch = torch.div(batch, Variable(std))
    return batch
```

Error message

```
(impaint_env) vivek@Viveks-MacBook-Pro image_impainter % python main.py
/Users/vivek/DSwork/image_impainter/impaint_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py:310: UserWarning: The use of the transforms.Scale transform is deprecated, please use transforms.Resize instead.
  warnings.warn("The use of the transforms.Scale transform is deprecated, " +
torch.Size([7])
torch.Size([7])
torch.Size([7, 3, 128, 128])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 114, in <module>
    fake = netG(input_cropped)
  File "/Users/vivek/DSwork/image_impainter/impaint_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vivek/DSwork/image_impainter/generator.py", line 70, in forward
    x = self.t7(x)
  File "/Users/vivek/DSwork/image_impainter/impaint_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vivek/DSwork/image_impainter/impaint_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 139, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/Users/vivek/DSwork/image_impainter/impaint_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vivek/DSwork/image_impainter/impaint_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 916, in forward
    return F.conv_transpose2d(
RuntimeError: Given transposed=1, weight of size [512, 256, 4, 4], expected input[7, 4000, 1, 1] to have 512 channels, but got 4000 channels instead
```

Comment: Please write a **descriptive title**, as explicitly advised in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `tensorflow`, please do not use irrelevant tags. (removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "gap" between layer `t6` and `t7` of your `generatorG`:

```py
        # ...
        self.t6 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=4000, kernel_size=(4, 4)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(4000),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

        self.t7 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels = 512, out_channels = 256, kernel_size =4, stride = 2, padding = 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        # ...
```

Your `t6` layer expects the input to have 512 channels and outputs a tensor with 4000 channels. However, the next layer, `t7`, expects the input to have only 512 channels.

You need to adjust either `t6` and `t7` such that `t6` will output *exactly* the same number of channels `t7` is expecting. That is `t6`'s `out_channles` ,just equal `t7`'s `in_channels`.